# How do I center the dots (SVG) with the class .stroke1

Tags: html, css

This is the needed code

```css
.strokes {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.stroke1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
            <div class="max-width">
                <div class="star star1"></div>

                <div class="home-content">
                    <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
                    <div class="text-2">Hadi Zouhbi</div>
                    <div class="text-3">And I'm a <span class="txt-rotate"
                         data-period="2000" 
                         data-rotate='[ "Developer.", "UX Designer.", " Programmer.", "Full-Stack Dev.", "Marketer" ]'
                         id="headSpan"></span></div>
                    <a href="#">Hire Me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>

    <div class="strokes">
    <svg class="stroke1" stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="3em" width="3em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M456 231a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0zm0 280a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0zm0 280a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

I want the stroke to be in the middle of the page but nothing is working , it always stays on the left side , am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: i do not get you ? @MisterJojo

Comment: Chill mate , I am still a beginner at this , no need to go off on me like that @MisterJojo

Comment: Can you include a quick mockup image that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is center the `<svg>` then there were a couple issues with your code. First, `justify-content` and `align-items` need to be set on the flex container itself (i.e. the same element that has the `display: flex` rule applied to it), not its children. Second, anything that is absolutely positioned will override any inherent `flex` positioning applied to it, so I don't think you want that in this case.

Here's an updated code snippet that addresses the above points and thus centers the dots.

```css
.strokes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.stroke1 {
  z-index: 1002;
}
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
            <div class="max-width">
                <div class="star star1"></div>

                <div class="home-content">
                    <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
                    <div class="text-2">Hadi Zouhbi</div>
                    <div class="text-3">And I'm a <span class="txt-rotate"
                         data-period="2000" 
                         data-rotate='[ "Developer.", "UX Designer.", " Programmer.", "Full-Stack Dev.", "Marketer" ]'
                         id="headSpan"></span></div>
                    <a href="#">Hire Me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>

    <div class="strokes">
    <svg class="stroke1" stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="3em" width="3em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M456 231a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0zm0 280a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0zm0 280a56 56 0 1 0 112 0 56 56 0 1 0-112 0z"></path></svg>
</div>
```